# Is Elementalist XP based on damage amount?

Tags: league-of-legends

In the new Lux skin, you get a new 'skin XP' system which collects elemental power based on the number of times you damage enemy champions. Is the elemental XP also based on the damage you do with your Q, E, R abilities?
Example: Would I get more XP (and faster skin change) if I had more AP to do damage with my Q, E and R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. The exp is solely based on landed abilities. This was confirmed on the dev stream riot did when the skin was first announced. You will gain just as much exp with 0 ap as you will with 600.

Comment: Can you link the vod or some sort of source ?

Comment: Sadly I'm at work rn and can't get on twitch to scour through the vods.

Comment: @dustyjuicebox Does game mode matter?